# How do I run doxygen from command prompt to generate html files

Tags: python-3.x, documentation, doxygen, documentation-generation, code-documentation

Need to generate python code doxygen document using automatic process.
while developing this need to run doxygen from command prompt, so I need windows command for that so I can run doxygen from command prompt and able to generate html file for documented python code.

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What did you try so far? Did you create a doxygen settings file? You could also use the doxywizard, so you can run doxygen from there.

Comment: I used doxywizard and created the the document but now I just want to use it through command prompt to make it automatic process.

Comment: Well it is just goto the right directory and run  `doxygen Doxyfile`.

Comment: Can you please help me the steps to execute it from cmd

Comment: Well it is just goto the right directory (see which directory you used in the doxywizard)  and run `doxygen Doxyfile`.